# in AWS cloudwatch dashboard, can i select to chart all dimensions of a metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Say, I want to chart CPU usage metric for each pod in my system, with `Podname` being the dimension. Can I specify a widget in CDK like this, and expect it to get all pods in one widget:

```
    const podcpumetric = new cloudwatch.Metric({
      namespace: 'chkk',
      metricName: 'CPU Metrics with podName as dimension',
      period: Duration.days(1),
 //   dimensionsMap: {}, // not specified so that all pods are in the widget
      statistic: 'maximum',
    });
    dashboard.addWidgets(
      new GraphWidget({
        title: 'Pod Cpu Usage',
        width: 12,
        left: [podcpumetric],
      }),
    );
```

I tried something like the above without specifying the dimension and hoping that it will get all pods' data. This does not seem to work.

I can however, declare one metric per pod, and then add it in the `left` array, but that doesn't seem a comprehensive solution. As I will have to update this widget, if I add a new pod in the future and want to chart its data.

Comment: Please try and let us know what did you find out.

Comment: @Marcin i should have added the conclusion there. It was not working for me, but wanted to ask the community in case i am missing something :)

Comment: have you tried the pasted code? what was the error?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no error. Just that it didn't work.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is possible. `Domain` is the only dimension in its dimensionSet.

```
    const CompanyLogins = new MathExpression({
      label: 'NumberOfDailyLoginsPerDomain',
      expression: `SEARCH(' {namespace, Domain} MetricName="NumberOfDailyLoginsPerDomain" ', 'Maximum', 1440)`,
      usingMetrics: {},
    });
    dashboard.addWidgets(
      new GraphWidget({
        title: 'Number of Logins per Domain (sum of logins by all users of the domain)',
        width: 12,
        view: cloudwatch.GraphWidgetView.BAR,
        left: [CompanyLogins],
      }),
    );
```

Comment: This is possible if you want just a single value per group, yes. You won't be able to show separate time-series (line graphs) like this. I don't think that was what the original question was about, is it?

Comment: I am able to get multiple line charts for the above query in the same widget, one line for each value of the `Domain`.